# Difficulty with Swift/Alamofire Completion Handlers

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire, completionhandler

Today I am using Alamofire to extract an int value. 
It's pulling the int fine, but I want to save the int value outside of the request (in a different function, viewDidLoad()).

I'm not sure how to call the completion handler, it doesn't seem to be doing anything at the moment.

Here is the method that extracts the int value in question (lastModified).

```
func checkVersion(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(versionCheckEndpoint).responseJSON { response in
        if(response.result.value != nil) {
            let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
            self.s3Endpoint = json["s3BucketURL"].stringValue
            let lastModified = json["lastModified"].intValue
            self.latestVersion = lastModified
        }
    }
}
```

I tried saving the value to an instance variable, this doesn't work.

I called the completion handler like this in viewDidLoad().. but I'm positive it's nowhere near correct:

```
 self.checkVersion() { response in
        self.latestVersion = response
    }
```

Can anyone give me some insight on how I can save the int value for lastModified to some local variable so it is not contained within the scope of the Alamofire request?

Answer (score 1):

In the function `checkVersion` the completion block isn't called.

You must call it after retrieving the value (although I would suggest to make it optional)

```
func checkVersion(_ completion: @escaping (Int?) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(versionCheckEndpoint).responseJSON { response in

        guard let value = response.result.value else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }

        let json = JSON(value)
        self.s3Endpoint = json["s3BucketURL"].stringValue
        let lastModified = json["lastModified"].intValue

        completion(lastModified)
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
self.checkVersion() { value in

    guard let value = value else {
        //handle invalid values here
        return
    }

    latestVersion = value
    // update the view if needed
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. 
Perhaps this has to do with the asynchronous nature of completion handlers, but if I try to print "latestVersion" or "self.latestVersion" after the call "self.checkVersion", the value of latestVersion still shows up as -1 (the default value that I provided.) 

It updates the value properly, but once the completion is over it goes back to default.

Comment: two things the value is provided only after running the completion block in alamofire response. second if you didn't wait for the response then you will get the default value. my answer shows where you should update the view or handle the error inside the block and not outside it.

Comment: I've placed "self.latestVersion = value" exactly in the "update the view if needed" comment, I'm simply just trying to use this value outside of the request/completion block. Maybe I can pass it to a different function to deal with it.

Comment: you can use the value but only after the completion is done it's asynchronous

Comment: It appears that I can only use the value while the completion code is executing -- after it has executed, the value is gone.